# App crashes randomly with sqlite exception

Tags: android, android-sqlite, realm, crashlytics

I got error below in Crashlytics from sqlite but in my whole app I didn't use sqlite I am only using realm database. Plz suggest anything missing.

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:780)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
   at bip.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:70)
   at bjg.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:32)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:818)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1525)
   at bkl.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:70)
   at blc.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:32)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Comment: But in my app I am not using SQLITE.